# Prove the f is integrable when $f(x)=(1-x^4)^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x)= (1-x^4)^{1/2}$ by $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. I need to prove the $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.
I think I need to use a partition but I have no idea how to prove the integrability or where to start.

Comment: Can't you just say that $f$ is continuous? Do you really need to use the basic definition of Riemann integrability?

Answer (score 0):

its enough to say $f$ is continuous..
 this is a composition of two continous functions such that 
$$f(x)=(g\circ h)(x)$$
where $g(x)=\sqrt x$ and $h(x)=1-x^4$